# Set optirun and g++ as compiler to compile OpenCL in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-construction, cmake, opencl

I am trying to compile an OpenCL example in Ubuntu and I need to use optirun (from the library Bumblebee) in order to circumvent the NVIDIA Optimus problem.

When using make, I need the output to be

```
optirun g++ ...
```

1. In the CMakeLists.txt file, I first tried SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER optirun g++) but it only generates `"optirun;g++" ...`
2. Cmake:

   SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "optirun g++")

Output:

```
"optirun g++" ...
```

Another Cmake:

```
include(CMakeForceCompiler)

CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(optirun g++ GNU_OCL)
```

Output:

```
optirun ...
```

Another Cmake:

```
include(CMakeForceCompiler)

CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER("optirun g++" GNU_OCL)
```

Output:

```
"optirun g++" ...
```

Comment: No experience with optirun, but surely the compiler doesn't care whether you do or do not have an OpenCL capable GPU installed?  As long as you have the required libraries, g++ should be happy.  Running your app would require the Nvidia GPU to be visible, so perhaps that is where optirun is needed?

Answer (score 1):

any OpenCL SDK comes with its own compiler, you are supposed to use that compiler.

Comment: I need to use g++ -lOpenCL for linking. As I understand it, optirun must preceed g++ for it to work because the computer cannot find the NVIDIA graphics card otherwise.